# Unit Test MVC 5 Controller Create Action with Unit of Work and Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to test a controller action that accepts a view model and creates a new entry. Here is the controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ContactViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View("Create", viewModel);

    _unitOfWork.Contacts.Add(Mapper.Map(viewModel, new Contact()));  

    _unitOfWork.Complete();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And the unit test:

```
[TestClass]
public class ContactControllerTests
{
    private ContactsController _controller;
    private Mock<IContactRepository> _mockRepository;
    private string _userId;
    private Mock<IUnitOfWork> _mockUoW;

    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void Init(TestContext context)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(c => c.AddProfile<MappingProfile>());
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        _userId = "1";
        _mockRepository = new Mock<IContactRepository>();
        _mockUoW = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();

        _mockUoW.SetupGet(u => u.Contacts).Returns(_mockRepository.Object);

        _controller = new ContactsController(_mockUoW.Object);

        _controller.MockCurrentUser(_userId, "user@domain.com");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CreatePost_ValidValuesSubmitted_ShouldCallComplete()
    {
        var viewModel = new ContactViewModel()
        {
            FirstName = "a",
            LastName = "b"
        };

        _controller.Create(viewModel);

        _mockRepository.Object.GetContacts(_userId).Should().HaveCount(1);
    }
}
```

The unit test always returns the count 0 while I expect it to be 1. I am pretty new to TDD and I implemented unit of work and repository pattern as shown in Mosh Hamedani's course at:
https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/full-stack-dot-net-developer-architecture-testing/table-of-contents

Comment: It's not TDD (Test *Driven*) if you're trying to test an already written piece of code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mocked any behavior for the repository in the above example.

Based on provided example, let's assume a simple interface like this.

```
public interface IContactRepository {
    void Add(Contact contact);
    IEnumerable<Contact> GetContacts(string _userId);
}
```

You need to have some form of storage for your data.

```
[TestInitialize]
public void TestInitialize() {
    _userId = "1";
    var data = new List<Contact>();//To store test data.
    //Configure repository
    _mockRepository = new Mock<IContactRepository>();
    _mockRepository.Setup(m => m.Add(It.IsAny<Contact>())).Callback<Contact>(data.Add);
    _mockRepository.Setup(m => m.GetContacts(_userId)).Returns(data);
    //Configure UoW
    _mockUoW = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    _mockUoW.SetupGet(u => u.Contacts).Returns(_mockRepository.Object);

    _controller = new ContactsController(_mockUoW.Object);

    _controller.MockCurrentUser(_userId, "user@domain.com");
}
```

or forego the mock and create a fake.

```
public class FakeContactRepository : IContactRepository {
    private ICollection<Contact> data;

    public FakeContactRepository(ICollection<Contact> data) {                
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void Add(Contact contact) {
        data.Add(contact);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Contact> GetContacts(string _userId) {
        return data;
    }
}
```

and set it up for the test.

```
[TestInitialize]
public void TestInitialize() {
    _userId = "1";
    var data = new List<Contact>();//To store test data.
    //Configure repository
    var fakeRepository = new FakeContactRepository(data);
    //Configure UoW
    _mockUoW = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    _mockUoW.SetupGet(u => u.Contacts).Returns(fakeRepository );

    _controller = new ContactsController(_mockUoW.Object);

    _controller.MockCurrentUser(_userId, "user@domain.com");
}
```