# Whats tests would sufficiently Unit Test a "Create" controller method in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq, repository-pattern

I want to test this (Controller Method) :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(SecurityQuestionViewModel securityQuestion)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SecurityQuestion dataModel = new SecurityQuestion();
        dataModel.questionText = securityQuestion.QuestionText;
        await _securityRepository.AddAsync(dataModel);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

My unit test (so far) looks like this ?

```
public async Task ModelContainsNewObjectAfterCreate()
{

    //Arrange

    _repository = new Mock<ISecurityQuestionRepository>();
    _repository.Setup(repo => repo.GetAllAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult(securityQuestion()));
    _controller = new SecurityQuestionsController(_repository.Object, _mapper);

    SecurityQuestion dataModel = new SecurityQuestion();
                     dataModel.questionText = "This is the new added question";
    SecurityQuestionViewModel sqvm = new SecurityQuestionViewModel();
    sqvm.QuestionText = dataModel.questionText;

    //Act
    var result = await _controller.Create(sqvm);

    //Assert

    var viewResult = Assert.IsType<RedirectToActionResult>(result);
    _repository.Verify(r => r.AddAsync(dataModel), Times.Once);

}
```

The `viewResult` passes.
The `_repository` verify does not.

It feels like I need to verify that the `AddAsync` method ran (would add a record to the existing repository). Perhaps my setup is wrong

It also feels like I need to validate the number of "questions" in the repository after the `AddAsync` method ran.

I am trying to understand what would constitute an adequate test and how to simulate the "Add" with the Moq.

Any insight would be appreciated.

This [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702552/unit-test-mvc-5-controller-create-action-with-unit-of-work-and-repository) seems close to what I want.

Comment: That is because the model was created within the method under test so it does not match. what you can do is use the `It.Is` with a predicate that matches the model properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test only following things in your action:

1. The case when the model is valid.
2. The case when the model is invalid.

There are only two cases. If the first case is satisfied you can verify that `AddAsync()` is executed with any parameter which is type `SecurityQuestion`.

You can mock `AddAsync()` like this:

```
repository.Setup(r => r.AddAsync(It.IsAny<SecurityQuestion>())
         .Returns(Task.FromResult(false));
```

And verify:

```
repository.Verify(r => r.AddAsync(It.IsAny<SecurityQuestion>()), Times.Once);
```

That is all which you can!

You cannot mock `SecurityQuestion` model because it uses `new` keyword and your code which try to mock should be removed.

This is all you need to do because your entire logic is if/else statement. Everything else will be executed normally. Only another thing which can behave unexpectedly is if `AddAsync()` throws an exception.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The verify fails because the model was created within the method under test so it does not match. what you can do is use the `It.Is` with a predicate that matches the model properties

```
_repository.Verify(r => r.AddAsync(It.Is<SecurityQuestion>(m => m.questionText == dataModel.questionText)), Times.Once);
```